# Windows 7 Not Loading

Tags: uefi, bootloader

Info from boot repair script:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23677510/

Windows 7 boot loader option is appearing, but instead loading Win 7, it takes me back to Ubuntu GRUB menu.

It says,

```
EFI/boot/bkpbootx64.efi not found
```

Comment: Did you install Windows in UEFI mode or Legacy mode? Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI mode or Legacy mode?

Comment: how can I found this? the system I have has a pre installed windows 7.. and I am installing Ubuntu from a pre configured USb. How can I check?

Answer (score 0):

Check if `/boot/efi` exists (in Ubuntu). If it is there, it means that you installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode, otherwise - in Legacy mode.

Comment: Yes.. /boot/efi exists

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64-signed`

Comment: it says: No error found

Comment: though I restarted the system, showing no progress